# combining arrays from sql query

Tags: php, arrays

i know this have been asked here for many times but i really couldn't figure out how to do this.
im getting this from wordpress sql request

```
$name = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Chipset FROM gpu", ARRAY_N);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => GeForce GTX 670
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fasdasd
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => GeForce GTX 670
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => GeForce GTX 560 Ti
        )

)
```

and for price

```
$price = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Price FROM gpu", ARRAY_N);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 403
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 288
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 288
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 288
        )

)
```

i need to create this format of array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => GeForce GTX 670
            [value] => 403 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => fasdasd
            [value] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => test
            [value] => 288
        )

)
```

If you know how to get results from two columns in one query and work with that array you can.
Also i wanna ask you guys if you could recommend me some good learning material where can i learn this type of combining arrays or how to use bunch of foreach's because i can't get my head around this

Ok solution to my problem is to change sql query but i want to know how to combine these arrays anyway for future.

Comment: Why can't you do `SELECT Price, Chipset from gpu`?

Comment: If you know this has been asked here many times, then why post another question instead of searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is `SELECT Chipset, Price FROM gpu` to fetch both columns in a single query. Since you're working with Wordpress, a good place to start is just looking through [their documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). It's going to be helpful to get a good grasp on SQL as well. I'd recommend [Tizag's MySQL Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/) for starters.